# Thanking, and criticizing, moderators for their actions

Tags: support, moderation, moderators

How can I thank a moderator for their help, and how can I air a criticism of a moderator's actions or behaviour?

I had posts wherein two different moderators intervened.

The first one was very helpful and I'd like to issue my thanks for their help.

The second one, took actions that I disagree with rather strongly. How might I make my disagreement/complaint regarding the decision known?

Comment: Further to nhinkles answer below we do have [chat] if you would prefer a more informal discussion than on meta. It's not private, but if you have something you want to discus and you think it might need some back and forth chatter then it is be another avenue.

Comment: Keep in mind that the community is moderated by itself and users [gain privileges] (http://superuser.com/help/privileges) as they progress. Moderators as I think you mean it might just be users performing actions rather than "diamond moderators" which [are elected](http://superuser.com/users?tab=moderators).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please keep in mind that being a moderator is a hard job – very much darned if you do, darned if you don't. Somebody will always be unhappy.

You can always post directly on meta if you have feedback, whether you're looking for an improvement or commending how something was handled. Please focus on the specific actions and behaviors though. Attacking somebody personally isn't constructive.

Some of us provide contact information directly on our user profiles. If a moderator voluntarily provides contact information, you are welcome to use that to provide them feedback. If a moderator chooses not to offer public contact information, do not attempt to find their personal contact information elsewhere.

You're also welcome to contact Stack Exchange with your comments. Use the [Contact](https://superuser.com/contact) link at the bottom of any page.

Comment: Yeah, I most certainly wouldn't make criticisms that were really just personal attacks. Rather, I'd try to give a reasonably objective explanation for why I believed the fellow was in error, not so much as to chastise him, but rather, to prompt him to give pause as to how he might improve his moderation methods, which in turn would help improve the site. So... "post directly on meta if you have feedback". ok, I'll try that a little later then.

Comment: @MercWithMouth you can also comment directly on the affected post if it's an issue specific to their handling of their post. "@moderatorsname, I disagree with <action> because <reason>, would you reconsider?" Oftentimes it may just be a misunderstanding (could be from either side) and can be resolved quickly and amicably.

Comment: Hmm, that's quite insightful, actually. You pretty much gave an all-purpose template, there. Thanks!